# How can I hide and show multiple divs and change each value

Tags: jquery, html, css, hide, show

**JS, CSS, HTML:**

```js
jQuery(function(){
  jQuery('#showall').click(function(){
    jQuery('.content').show();
  });
  
  jQuery('#button').click(function(){
    jQuery('#extracontent'+$(this).attr('target')).slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
h1 {font-family:Oswald; text-shadow:1px 1px 0px crimson; color:white;}
h2 {font-family:Rokkitt; color:crimson; letter-spacing:-1px;}
#area1 {background-color:#323232; margin-bottom:10px; padding:10px;}
#area2 {background-color:#323232; margin-bottom:10px; padding:10px;}
#area3 {background-color:#323232; margin-bottom:10px; padding:10px;}

button {padding:5px; border-radius:0px; -webkit-appearance:none; border:none; font-size:18px; width:80px;  height:40px; color:white; background-color:crimson; font-family:Oswald;}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rokkitt|Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="all-content">
  <div class="content" id="area1" target="1">
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <h2>Here is some sub-text</h2>
    <button id="button" class="button1" target="1" value="Hide">Hide</button>

    <div class="extra-content" id="extracontent1" target="1">
      <p>Here is some extra content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="content" id="area2" target="2">
    <h1>Heading 2</h1>
    <h2>Here is some sub-text</h2>
    <button id="button" class="button2" target="2" value="Hide">Hide</button>

    <div class="extra-content" id="extracontent2" target="2">
      <p>Here is some extra content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="content" id="area3" target="2">
    <h1>Heading 3</h1>
    <h2>Here is some sub-text</h2>
    <button id="button" class="button3" target="3" value="Hide">Hide</button>

    <div class="extra-content" id="extracontent3" target="3">
      <p>Here is some extra content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: more context please.  What values need to change? what have you tried? what needs to hide/show and when? where is the button with `id` of `#showall`?

Comment: What did you mean with "change each value" ?

Comment: **Tip:** Instead of creating three identical rules for `#area1`, `#area2` and `#area3`... you can just do this: `#area1,#area2,#area3 {...}`

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't working because you use the same ID for multiple elements. ID's must be unique, only one element can have one ID. Use classes instead.
And I see that you do use unique classes, you probably just got those two mixed up.

**See example:**

```js
jQuery(function(){
  jQuery('#showall').click(function(){
    jQuery('.content').show();
  });
  
  jQuery('.button').click(function(){
    jQuery('#extracontent'+$(this).attr('target')).slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
h1 {font-family:Oswald; text-shadow:1px 1px 0px crimson; color:white;}
h2 {font-family:Rokkitt; color:crimson; letter-spacing:-1px;}
#area1,#area2,#area3 {background-color:#323232; margin-bottom:10px; padding:10px;}

button {padding:5px; border-radius:0px; -webkit-appearance:none; border:none; font-size:18px; width:80px;  height:40px; color:white; background-color:crimson; font-family:Oswald;}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rokkitt|Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="all-content">
  <div class="content" id="area1" target="1">
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <h2>Here is some sub-text</h2>
    <button class="button" id="button1" target="1" value="Hide">Hide</button>

    <div class="extra-content" id="extracontent1" target="1">
      <p>Here is some extra content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="content" id="area2" target="2">
    <h1>Heading 2</h1>
    <h2>Here is some sub-text</h2>
    <button class="button" id="button2" target="2" value="Hide">Hide</button>

    <div class="extra-content" id="extracontent2" target="2">
      <p>Here is some extra content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="content" id="area3" target="2">
    <h1>Heading 3</h1>
    <h2>Here is some sub-text</h2>
    <button class="button" id="button3" target="3" value="Hide">Hide</button>

    <div class="extra-content" id="extracontent3" target="3">
      <p>Here is some extra content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

- If you wanted, you could change this line:
  `jQuery('#extracontent'+$(this).attr('target')).slideToggle();`
  to this line:
  `jQuery($(this).next('.extra-content')).slideToggle();` *(http://api.jquery.com/next/)*.
  This way you don't need the `target` or the `id` tag in your HTML.
- In your CSS, instead of creating three identical rules for `#area1`, `#area2` and `#area3`... you can just do this: `#area1,#area2,#area3 {...}`. (I already implemented it in my answer code.)
- As for the `jQuery('#showall').click(function(){`... There is no element with `id="showall"` in your code, so at the moment this code doesn't do anything. But when you add that element, the code should work too.

I don't understand what you mean by "change each value", and I don't see any code that would serve that purpose. If you could elaborate on that, I'll try and find you a solution for that too...

Answer (score 0):

try this js code and enjoy.........

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery('.button1').click(function(){
     jQuery('#extracontent1').slideToggle();
 });
 jQuery('.button2').click(function(){
     jQuery('#extracontent2').slideToggle();
 });
 jQuery('.button3').click(function(){
     jQuery('#extracontent3').slideToggle();
 });
});
```

```css
h1 {font-family:Oswald; text-shadow:1px 1px 0px crimson; color:white;}
h2 {font-family:Rokkitt; color:crimson; letter-spacing:-1px;}
#area1 {background-color:#323232; margin-bottom:10px; padding:10px;}
#area2 {background-color:#323232; margin-bottom:10px; padding:10px;}
#area3 {background-color:#323232; margin-bottom:10px; padding:10px;}

button {padding:5px; border-radius:0px; -webkit-appearance:none; border:none; font-size:18px; width:80px;  height:40px; color:white;
 background-color:crimson; font-family:Oswald;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="all-content">
<div class="content" id="area1" target="1">
 
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <h2>Here is some sub-text</h2>
 <button id="button" class="button1" target="1" value="Hide">Hide</button>
    
    <div class="extra-content" id="extracontent1" target="1">
     
        <p>Here is some extra content</p>
    
    </div>
    
</div>

<div class="content" id="area2" target="2">

 <h1>Heading 2</h1>
    <h2>Here is some sub-text</h2>
 <button id="button" class="button2" target="2" value="Hide">Hide</button>
 
    <div class="extra-content" id="extracontent2" target="2">
     
        <p>Here is some extra content</p>
    
    </div>
    
</div>


<div class="content" id="area3" target="2">

 <h1>Heading 3</h1>
    <h2>Here is some sub-text</h2>
 <button id="button" class="button3" target="3" value="Hide">Hide</button>

    <div class="extra-content" id="extracontent3" target="3">
     
        <p>Here is some extra content</p>
    
    </div>
    
</div>


</div>
```